# Troubles with Facebook long-live token

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uwp, windows-10

How can I see actual expired time for long-live token? When I should update it and how do it?

My steps:

1. Login via WebAuthenticationBroker (UWP - Windows 10)
2. Get shot-live token
3. Get long-live token. Expired after 2 month.

How can I know than I should clear data and invoke broker again? And why I can't refresh token without input login/password in broker?

Comment: you update it when it´s expired. you know it´s expired when it does not work anymore. not sure what you mean with the last question, refreshing/renewing a token only works with user interaction, of course.

Comment: @luschn, Help me please understand this logic. For ex. google auth:
Login. Take token. When it is expired update it by other API method (for ex. "refresh_token"). For Facebook -> I don't understand how I should update/refresh token. I can receive it and all.

Comment: for example, this function refreshes the token even without redirection: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: @luschn, but it is only for JS. Sorry, but I didn't find REST (etc) for use in Windows 10 :( And I didn't see refreshing token in the method's description

Comment: You can not create a new token without user interaction. The user has to login to your app again (implicitly, by visiting a website where the JS SDK is embedded, would be enough.)

Comment: @CBroe, so...if I login via browser (for ex.) and user was used this time my app -> after 2 month I should show broker again?